# esri/dijit/Search multiple sources not updating drop down list

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, search

I am trying to reproduce the tutorial on one of my own layers

[Here](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/search_multiplesources/)

I have put in one of my own layers

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
       <title>ArcGIS API for JavaScript | Search widget with multiple sources</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
       <style>
          html,
          body,
          #map {
             height: 100%;
             width: 100%;
             margin: 0;
             padding: 0;
          }
          #search {
             display: block;
             position: absolute;
             z-index: 2;
             top: 20px;
             left: 74px;
          }
       </style>


    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>
       <script>
          require([
            "esri/map", "esri/dijit/Search", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Extent", "dojo/domReady!"
          ], function (Map, Search, FeatureLayer, InfoTemplate, SpatialReference, Extent) {
             var map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "gray",
                center: [-97, 38], // lon, lat
                zoom: 5
             });

             var s = new Search({
                enableButtonMode: true, //this enables the search widget to display as a single button
                enableLabel: false,
                enableInfoWindow: true,
                showInfoWindowOnSelect: false,
                map: map
             }, "search");

             var sources = s.get("sources");

             //Push the sources used to search, by default the ArcGIS Online World geocoder is included. In addition there is a feature layer of US congressional districts. The districts search is set up to find the "DISTRICTID". Also, a feature layer of senator information is set up to find based on the senator name. 

             sources.push({
                featureLayer: new FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/CongressionalDistricts/FeatureServer/0"),
                searchFields: ["DISTRICTID"],
                displayField: "DISTRICTID",
                exactMatch: false,
                outFields: ["DISTRICTID", "NAME", "PARTY"],
                name: "Congressional Districts",
                placeholder: "3708",
                maxResults: 6,
                maxSuggestions: 6,

                //Create an InfoTemplate and include three fields
                infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Congressional District", "District ID: ${DISTRICTID}</br>Name: ${NAME}</br>Party Affiliation: ${PARTY}"),
                enableSuggestions: true,
                minCharacters: 0
             });

             sources.push({
                featureLayer: new FeatureLayer("http://maps.eastriding.gov.uk/arcgis/rest/services/GISIntranet/MapServer/0"),
                searchFields: ["ADDRESS_WITHOUT_BREAKS"],
                displayField: "ADDRESS_WITHOUT_BREAKS",
                exactMatch: false,
                name: "ADDRESS_WITHOUT_BREAKS",
                outFields: ["*"],
                placeholder: "ADDRESS_WITHOUT_BREAKS",
                maxResults: 6,
                maxSuggestions: 6,

                //Create an InfoTemplate

                //infoTemplate: new InfoTemplate("Senator information", "Name: ${Name}</br>State: ${State}</br>Party Affiliation: ${Party}</br>Phone No: ${Phone_Number}<br><a href=${Web_Page} target=_blank ;'>Website</a>"),

                enableSuggestions: true,
                minCharacters: 0
             });

             //Set the sources above to the search widget
             s.set("sources", sources);

             s.startup();

          });
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="search"></div>
       <div id="map"></div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

but when I start typing in the text box it does not create a dropdown list. I cannot see a difference from my source to the other source that gives you a dropdown list

Comment: Check your dev tools and see if you're getting an error and your network traffic to see if you're getting the required resources.  I copied your code above and was able to get results from the world geocoder.

Comment: @Branco Thanks for your reply. I have no problem with the geocoder and the Congressional District search. When you start typing in the box on both of those layers will start displaying a suggestion under the box (its like autocomplete). It is when I select my layer there is no suggestion . There is no errors in the dev tools and when I look at the network, each letter you type will fire a search on the geocode but not on my own (ADDRESS_WITHOUT_BREAKS). If you blindly type in a search on my layer and hit enter it will search the layer and zoon to point. Its just that autocomplete wont work.

Comment: I have the same issue to address here. I can't use suggestion because our ArcGIS server is 10.2 but the first retrieve value is not necessarily what I need.
Do you have another approach?

Comment: I have a feature service published with ArcGIS Server 10.3 but I am having the issues described by Easty :(

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the API reference for [Search](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/search-amd.html#enablesuggestions):

> "available if working with a 10.3 geocoding service that has suggest capability loaded or a 10.3 feature layer that supports pagination, i.e. supportsPagination = true."

This means you need with a Feature Service published to ArcGIS Online or version 10.3 of ArcGIS Server.

I think it would be pretty helpful for the doc specific to 'sources' > `enableSuggestions` linked to the same so i'll inform the team.